# App engine. Forced to single instance

Tags: google-app-engine

I make server for simple realtime multiplayer game, on google app engine, Python SDK.
Requests very simple, and process in 1ms maximum.
I hold all game data in static variables of instane.
I set 'Min Pending Latency' to 15 sec. for prevent spawn of second instance.
But some time second instance has created any way.

How i can disable, or kill second instance, if it has ben spawn, And process all requests in single instance only?

Answer (score 2):

If you're fighting against the system, that's an indication that you're doing something wrong.

You should not try to manage all your requests inside a single instance. That defeats the whole purpose of using GAE. The problem of course is that you shouldn't be storing your data as static variables inside your instance. Even apart from the issues with other instances being started, every instance is stopped and restarted every so often: so your data would be lost.

You should keep your data in the places meant for that: in memcache, and in the datastore.

Comment: i no need save any data after restart. In application setting, 15 second waiting, before spawn new instance. But new instance spawn without any waiting.

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make sense then. If you need data to persist globally across requests, it also needs to persist across instance restarts, since these can happen at *any time*. If you don't need data to persist, then don't keep it in global variables.

Comment: I use single instance, just like proxy data exchanger betveen players. No nees save data longer that 5-6 seconds. Answer of Aki, below, already give way, to hold server in single instance. Thank you anyway. Probably later, ill make second, heawy version of server, with multiply instances, and megring of data by memcache.

Answer (score 0):

beside only 8 instance-hours is free,
you can do this with Module + Manual Scaling

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

Comment: Thank you Aki, : ) i add:

instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 10m

to app.yaml class. Is right? Or need additional changes in application? Or need enable Modules?

Comment: sadly i never tried module. i satisfied with Idle Instances: ( Automatic – 1 ) in performance settings,it's free.

Comment: i have Max Idle Instances = 1 too, but it no prevent spawning of more that one instance. Any way, thank you, i will watch to instances with new settings in app.yaml